# How to show help for all subparsers in argparse when using a Class()

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

very new to working with argparse and the cmd line. I've started to build a parser that allows for a front-end user to enter in data via the cmd terminal. The parser is calling the API() class that I have created (which creates the SQLALCHEMY session and etc.), example shown here:

```
class API(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # all the session / engine config here

    def create_user(self, username, password, firstname, lastname, email):
        new_user = User(username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
        self.session.add(new_user)
        self.session.commit()
        print(username, firstname, lastname) 

    def retrieve_user(self, username, firstname, lastname):
       # code here ... etc .
```

to implement in the CMD file here:

```
def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='API_ArgParse', description='Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) Interface Commands')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
        title='subcommands', description='valid subcommands', help='additional help')    

    api = API() # calling the API class functions/engine 

    # Create command for 'user' 
    create_parser = subparsers.add_parser('create_user', help='create a user') 
    create_parser.add_argument('username', type=str, help='username of the user')
    create_parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='password')
    create_parser.add_argument('firstname', type=str, help='first name')
    create_parser.add_argument('lastname', type=str, help='last name')
    create_parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='email address')
    #args = parser.parse_args() <--EDIT:removed from here and placed on bottom
    api.create_user(args.username, args.password, args.firstname, args.lastname, args.email)       

    # Retrieve command for 'user'
    retrieve_parser = subparsers.add_parser('retrieve_user', help='retrieve a user')
    retrieve_parser.add_argument('username', type=str, help='username')
    retrieve_parser.add_argument('firstname', type=str, help='first name')
    retrieve_parser.add_argument('lastname', type=str, help='last name')
    api.retrieve_user(args.username, args.firstname, args.lastname)
```

**NEW EDIT/ADDITION** OF args = parser.parse_args() to use both commands to reflect comments below.

```
     args = parser.parse_args() 
     print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and so on...

My **problem** is that the terminal is NOT printing the help command for the new parsers (e.g. retrieve_parser, update_parser, etc.). Do I have to create a "args = parser.parse_arg()" per section? 
Secondly, do I create a "args = create_parser.parse_args()" in-place of just "parser.parse..." I notice they print two different things on the terminal.

Any clarification about where to place the parse_arg() method (taking into consideration the use of the API() function) is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: When trying to call retrieve_user from the terminal, I get the following error: `usage: API_ArgParse [-h] {create_user} ...
API_ArgParse: error: invalid choice: 'retrieve_user' (choose from 'create_user')`

Comment: The first time you call `parse_args` all you have defined is `create_user`.  That's what the error message is telling you.  Put the `parse_args` after creating all the subparsers.

Comment: I've put `args = parser.parse_args()` at the very end (after all my subparsers) and now I'm getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/notssdb-cmd", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/notssdb-cmd", line 25, in main
    api.create_user(args.username, args.password, args.firstname, args.lastname, args.email)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'args' referenced before assignment` which makes sense because args is now defined at the bottom. I'll reflect this with appropriate markings for edits done.

Comment: Perhaps this is an instance where I should build IF/ ELIF/ELIF statements so that the parser goes through the commands until the correct one is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you call the `parse_args` method after you have created the `parser` (and that includes any subparsers), and before you need to use the resulting Namespace (usually called `args`).

```
retrieve_parser.add_argument('lastname', type=str, help='last name')

args = parser.parse_args()  # <=========

api.retrieve_user(args.username, args.firstname, args.lastname)
```

The purpose of `parse_args` is to read the `sys.argv` list (which the shell/interpreter created from your command line), and 'parse' it using the specficiations you created with `add_argument` and so on.

The main `parser` 'knows' about the subparsers, and will pass the argv list to the appropriate one (as selected by names like 'retrieve_user').

If the the command line includes `-h` (or `--help`) the parser will display a help message and exit.  This message lists the subparsers, but does not show their arguments.  If `-h` follows a subparser name, it's the subparser that will display the help.

```
python main.py -h     # main help
python main.py retrieve_user -h   # subparser help
```

`parser.print_help()` can be used in your code to show that same help message. `retrieve_parser.print_help()` will do the same for the subparser.  Obviously these commands will only work within `main`, and are of more use when debugging (not production).

There's no provision in `argparse` to display the help for all subparsers.  However you could construct such a function from the `print_help` commands that I just described.  There probably is a SO answer with such a function (but I don't know what would be good search term).

Crudely, `main()` could include:

```
 parser.add_argument('--bighelp', action='store_true', help='show help for all subparsers')
 ....
 if args.bighelp:
      parser.print_help()
      subparser1.print_help()
      subparser2.print_help()
      ....
      sys.exit(1)  # if want to quit
```

It's possible to get a list of the subparsers from the parser, but it's probably easier and clearer to maintain your own list.

---

I was focusing on how to get the `parser` working, not on the next step of calling the `api`.

You need to modify the `add_subparsers`, adding a `dest` parameter.

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd',
    title='subcommands', description='valid subcommands', help='additional help')
```

Then after you have define all subparsers do:

```
# should call cmd since I have stored `.dest` there e.g.`subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd'...`
 args = parser.parse_args()
 if args.cmd in ['create_user']:  # or just == 'create_user'
     api.create_user(args...)
 elif args.cmd in ['retrieve_user']:
     api.retrieve_user(args...)
```

The argparse docs shows how you can streamline this by invoking:

```
 args.subcmdfunc(args)
```

See the last 2 examples in the sub-commands section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Either way, the idea is to find out from the `args` namespace which subcommand the user specified, and then calling the correct `api` method.

Keep in mind that `parser.parse_args()` is equivalent to `parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])`.  So whatever parser you use, whether the main one or one of subparsers, it must be prepared to handle all the strings that your user might give.  It's the main parser that knows how to handle the subparser names.  The subparser only has to handle the strings that follow its name.  It will probably give an error if given the full `argv[1:]` list.  So normally you don't call `parse_args` for a specific subparser.

Comment: I've called the 'parse_args' method after each new 'parser' but it still doesn't show on the terminal, only 'create_user'.

Comment: So would I need to call the __parse_args__ method per subparser or does calling it at the very end of all my subparsers work? @hpaulj

Comment: Note added on invoking the `api` methods.

Comment: ++ I looked up `args.subcmdfunc(args)` but didn't find anything in the argparse docs.

Comment: I had in mind the last 2 examples in this section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands